# Why is my internal storage full if I dont even have any apps that is big im usibg a Huawei GT3

Tags: storage

As shown in the picture below:

[image: Storage]
<sup>Storage (click for larger image)</sup>

Comment: Hard to tell. All that can be said by the information you provided: There are 15GB of "other files". May I suggest you check with our relevant tag-wikis first: [storage](/tags/storage/info), **[internal-storage](/tags/internal-storage/info)** (especially check the links at the end of it), [insufficient-memory](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) (agan some useful links at the end). Then [edit] your question and add some helpful details – or even [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) if you were able to solve the issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to reset your phone from **FACTORY DATA REST** 
To reset your phone from factory data reset

> Go to settings>Backup and reset>factory data reset>RESET PHONE

I have also experienced this problem in my **Lenovo A2010** 
Probably I had used only 500mb out of 4GB but then also only 200mb was available.
After factory data reset the problem was solved and 2.5GB was available...

**NOTE:-Before resetting you should backup your data on SD card and remove SD card and sims from your device before resetting.**